# How to install libmodbus on Windows for C++? Are there any other alternative modbus libraries?

Tags: c++, installation, modbus

I need to work with Modbus RTU on C++. I have been trying to follow the instructions on https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus but I couldn't really get the hang of it. Could someone who knows how to install it please help me? And if not libmodbus some alternative Modbus library suggestions could help too.

Here is some extra information that might help:

- I work with Windows 8.1, 64 bit
- I code C++ on Code::Blocks

Thank you in advance!